# How to avoid apex method executes multiple times?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

By Clicking the submitPopup button from UI I'm executing some logic to assign the case owner but every time by clicking button the logic executes.
How can we avoid it run every time. The logic needs to run only for the first time click on submit button.
Can anyone please help how to stop it.

this.changeOwner(); needs to run on first time only

Html:

```html
<lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small" variant="brand" name="Yes" onclick={submitPopup}  label="Yes" style="margin-right: 20px;"></lightning-button>
```

JS

```js
import { LightningElement, api, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { getRelatedListRecords } from 'lightning/uiRelatedListApi';
import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue }  from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import changeOwnerCase from '@salesforce/apex/CaseCreationsController.changeOwnerCase';
import OWNER_NAME from '@salesforce/schema/Case.OwnerId';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import Id from '@salesforce/user/Id';
import UserNameFIELD from '@salesforce/schema/User.Name';

export default class ET_EMEASecondaryTradingLWC extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
 @api recordId ;
     getStateParameters(currentPageReference) {
        if (currentPageReference) {
            this.recordId = currentPageReference.attributes.recordId;
        }
    }

    submitPopup(){
        this.isConfirm = true;
        this.changeOwner();
        this.handleSubmit(this.event);
   }

   changeOwner(){
        this.isLoading = true;
        changeOwnerCase({ csId :this.recordId})
        .then(result =>{
            const event = new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Success',
                message: 'Case Owner is assigned Successfully',
                variant: 'Success',
                mode: 'pester'
            });

            this.isLoading = false;
            this.dispatchEvent(event);
            this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                type: 'standard__recordPage',
                attributes: {
                    recordId: this.recordId,
                    objectApiName: 'Case',
                    actionName: 'view'
                }
            });                     
        }
    }
}
```

Apex Class

```
 @AuraEnabled
 public static boolean changeOwnerCase(String csId){
     boolean returnVar ;     
     Case caseRecord = [select id, ET_Request_Type__c, recordtype.developername, OwnerId, ET_Request_Template__c from Case where id = :csId];    
     if(caseRecord.Recordtype.DeveloperName == 'EMEA_FCT'){
       returnVar = changeOwnerFCTCase(caseRecord); 
     }else if(caseRecord.Recordtype.DeveloperName == 'EMEA_Servicing'){
        returnVar = changeOwnerServicingCase(caseRecord); 
     }
     
     return returnVar;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Another potential solution is to add a "disabled" state for the button and then manage the state in the class.

Something like this:

HTML

```
<lightning-button
    class="slds-m-top_small"
    variant="brand"
    name="Yes"
    onclick={submitPopup}
    label="Yes"
    style="margin-right: 20px;"
    disabled={isButtonDisabled}>
</lightning-button>
```

JS

```
export default class ET_EMEASecondaryTradingLWC extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
  isButtonDisabled = false;

  submitPopup(){
    this.isButtonDisabled = true;
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I was going to suggest this in my answer but I couldn't find the `disabled` option in the documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-button/specification

Comment: @fred Yeah it is strange they dont have it under the Specification tab but I can confirm it works.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a variable to store whether the button had been clicked once.

Inside the class, add `isButtonClicked = false;`

Then amend your `submitPopup` method:

```
submitPopup(){
    if(!this.isButtonClicked){
        this.isButtonClicked = true;
        this.isConfirm = true;
        this.changeOwner();
        this.handleSubmit(this.event);
    }
}
```